# How does the control of a three-phase PWM rectifier work?

Tags: power-electronics, pwm, control, rectifier, three-phase

I have been studying the control of three-phase PWM rectifiers i.e. control of the below power electronics circuit:

[image]

This circuit can be modeled with exploiting of the space vectors in the stationary reference frame based on this equation:

$$\hat{v}^{\alpha\beta}_g = R_f\cdot\hat{i}^{\alpha\beta}_f + L_f\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\hat{i}^{\alpha\beta}_f + \hat{v}^{\alpha\beta}_c,$$

where the \$\hat{v}^{\alpha\beta}_g\$ is the space vector of the grid voltage, \$\hat{v}^{\alpha\beta}_c\$ is the space vector of the converter voltage, \$\hat{i}^{\alpha\beta}_f\$ is the space vector of the current through the inductors. The equation above corresponds to this equivalent circuit in the stationary reference frame:

[image]

For current control purposes it is advantageous to avoid the harmonic values so it is advantageous apply the *Park transform* on the above equation mentioned above.

The equation in the synchronous reference frame (oriented by the space vector of the grid voltage):

$$\hat{v}^{dq}_g = R_f\cdot\hat{i}^{dq}_f + L_f\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\hat{i}^{dq}_f + j\omega L_f\cdot\hat{i}^{dq}_f + \hat{v}^{dq}_c$$

This equation can be decomposed into the *d* and *q* axes. The decomposition corresponds to the following equivalent circuits:

[image]

Now suppose negligible resistance of the input inductors (\$R_f = 0\$), the steady state condition (\$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\hat{i}^{dq}_f = 0\$) and current drawn from the grid with unity power factor. In such a case I think that I can draw the phasor diagram for the first harmonics in the synchronous reference frame in this form:

[image]

Now let's say I would like to have a higher DC link voltage \$v_{dc}\$. In such a situation the converter needs to draw a higher active current from the grid i.e. the control algorithm of the rectifier needs to modify the voltage produced by the rectifier according to the phasor diagram below. It means that the converter voltage needs to be modified in such a manner that a higher voltage drop on the inductor occurs at first. Based on that the inductor current increases.

[image]

Based on this phasor diagram it seems to me that for the increase of the active current drawn from the grid it is needed to have more negative the *q* component and unchanged the *d* component of the voltage \$\hat{v}^{dq}_c\$ produced by the converter.

**My question is why the *d* component of the converter voltage should be unchanged for the greater active current?** This behavior isn't in accordance with the equivalent circuit for the *d* axis. Based on the equivalent circuit for the *d* axis I expect that for the greater active current lower *d* component of the converter voltage is necessary.

Comment: I am not following everything in your question. But I have practical experience using field-oriented control (FOC) with regen. For the most part, the D-axis current is always maintained at zero, since the D-axis current does not produce torque and therefore cannot contribute to the output power of a generator. Q-axis current can be adjusted using a control loop to maintain a particular generator output. Of course, you have to make sure you don't allow the control loop to command a Q-axis current that is too high for your system.

Comment: The only time that D-axis current is used is when the back EMF is close to or above the DC link voltage. When that happens, D-axis current is commanded as a way of implementing "field weakening."